# PDFTron. Convert annotations to svg

Tags: .net, pdf, svg, annotations, pdftron

I need to scan pdf document, extract some metadata from annotations, get it svg representation, and save it to database. I am using PDFTron and .NET for pdf processing.

During my research, I have found two ways to do it:

1. Extract `fdf` data from initial document. Lets name it `in_pdf`
2. Create empty pdf file and merge it with `fdf` doc. So I can get pdf only with annotations. Lets name it `temp_pdf`
3. Convert `temp_pdf` to svg.
4. Open `in_pdf`, and try to find corresponding svg tag for every annotation. But I do not know, how to find corresponding tag

The second way:

1. Extract `fdf` data from initial document for every annnotaion. In fact, make separate `fdf` for every annotaion.
2. Merge it with empty `temp_pdf`. In fact, make separate `pdf` for every annotation.
3. Convert each `temp_pdf` to svg. Using this way, gives me mapping between each annnotation and its svg string. But causes creation many temporary documents.

All the stuff would be much simplier, if I have some instrument to convert each annotation in svg directly, not the whole document. Is there a way to do it,  using PDFTron?

Comment: Could you clarify why converting annotations to SVG is important for you? Also, are you interested in just the visual appearance of the annotation, or also the internal contents/metadata?

Comment: I need to display annots in custom web viewer, which works with svg, and already has something like markup. They display pdf in svg , and I need to display annots on top of it. But annote should not be the part of pdf. When I upload pdf on server, I should clear it from all annots, make some objects from this annots and display them as svg on top of initial pdf. I also need internal metada, but I can read it from annot object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the appearance of annotations to a PDF page, and then you can convert that page to SVG.

This forum post shows how to render a specific annotation to an image.
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pdfnet-sdk/s8eeLmyNuGc/b_0gA02He3IJ

To customize that code to your use case, the following should work great.
For SVG generation you can do the following.

```
Page temp_page = doc.PageCreate();
temp_page.AnnotPushBack(annot);
annot.Flatten(temp_page); // move annotation content stream into page content stream, and remove the annotation
temp_page.SetMediaBox(temp_page.GetVisibleContentBox())
Convert.ToSvg(temp_page, "out_path", svg_options);
```

From here you can use standard XML tools to merge this SVG content to your target SVG file.

To position the annotation, and size, the annotation, you would call

```
annot.GetRect()
```

The x1,y1 values give you the **bottom** left, corner, and x2,y2 gives you top right corner.

The generated SVG output has the same scale as the PDF, so you can use the values as is.

Comment: Great, it works! But I also need to save position of annotation. If I use provided code, all annotaions are displayed in top left corner of result svg, even if it in bottom right corner of original pdf. How can I get svg with correct positions?

Comment: And, by the way, `Flatten call` does not remove annotation from initial pdf

Comment: Also I have some problem with `Popup` annots. For example, I have popup for arrow. How can I insert the popup in the same svg as arrow?

Comment: Regarding the Flatten not removing the annotation, we added the annotation to a temporary page, and flattened that instance. We did not call flatten on the original page, so the annotation remains there. So what you observed is expected.

Comment: And what about Popup annotations?

Comment: They are not actually part of the page, like a "normal" annotation. They have Rect, which is supposed to define where they appear on the page, when the Parent annotation is double clicked. But this is not required. Often on mobile, the popup simply takes up the whole screen. So, I would just call GetContents on the annotation (it checks the Popup) and put that somewhere in your UI. If you are not aware, we offer a HTML5 document viewer, that already has full annotation support. www.pdftron.com/webviewer

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for this great explanation. if possible, do you mind looking at this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479423/highlighter-opacity-effect-pdftron-to-svg